# Constant value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a drawing application. In `App.js` I declare a constant value brushSize like this, which is by default 5:

```
  const [brushSize, setBrushSize] = React.useState('5');
```

Then I have some select options, to select a brushsize:

```
 <select
        value={brushSize}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setBrushSize(e.target.value);
        }}
      >
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
```

Whenever user changes the `brushsize`, the brushSize gets a new value (`e.target.value`).

To draw, user has to click on the `Line` button:

```
<button variant="secondary" onClick={drawLine}>
          Line
        </button>
```

Whenever said button is clicked, the following happens:

```
const drawLine = () => {
    addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, brushSize);
  };
```

`addLine` gets called (`addLine` is a function from another js file, and yes the file is imported and working with `App.js`) with a few parameters, the last one is `brushSize`.

This is my other file, the `line.js`. There you can see it passes brushSize to strokeWidth:

```
export const addLine = (stage, layer, mode = "brush", brushSize) => {
    alert(brushSize);
  let isDrawing = false;
  let lastLine;
  stage.on("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
    isDrawing = true;
    let pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
    lastLine = new Konva.Line({
      stroke: mode == "brush" ? "red" : "white",
      strokeWidth: brushSize,
```

I used the `alert(brushSize)` to see what happens whenever the `brushSize` is passed from `App.js` to `line.js addLine` function. The problem is that it's always `undefined`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: JS doesn't care about the names of arguments, just their order. You need `export const addLine = (stage, layer, brushSize, mode = "brush") => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass in 3 arguments.

```
addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, brushSize);
```

But you assume 4.

```
export const addLine = (stage, layer, mode = "brush", brushSize) => {
```

Try pass 4 arguments like:

```
addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, undefined, brushSize);
```